# The Java Wiki Bot Framework logging

Tags: java, debugging, mediawiki, slf4j

I am using [The Java Wiki Bot Framework](http://jwbf.sourceforge.net/) to do changes in a mediawiki website using java, and it works fine. The only problem is that the JWBF produces a a huge volume of debugging information in the console of my application that is overshadowing my output and make it hard to find, visually. is their anyway that I could stop the logging for JWBF? BTW, JWBF uses SL4J for logging.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slf4j related topic. If no logger binding is defined, you see the following

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

If you add a binding e.g. [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html), you can reduce logging output. Your logback.xml should contains a line like

```
 ...
 <logger name="net.sourceforge.jwbf" level="ERROR"/>
 ...
```

For more details see [Logback configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)